# Get angle for ear clipping

Tags: polygon, ear, triangulation

I am trying to implement a ear clipping algorithm into a program of mine but I am having issues. While that I can get it to work in a lot of situations, I haven't found a good way to check for reflex angles.

I've been looking up ways - every method I've tried to date seems to have angle it won't work for. When I try to find more information, most people's tutorials/work just tell me to "find the reflex angle and test for ear" then describe how to test for ear but not how to get the reflex angle.

Can anyone tell me how to get the proper angle inside the triangle for a concave polygon, or point me in the right direction? Could be an understanding issue with me. Thanks.

Comment: It's simple enough to get the angle of each side with atan2. All you need to do to find reflex angles then is figure out which side of a side is the polygon's inside.

Comment: I got that already yes, how do I find if the triangle is inside the polygon given it could be concave and shaped like a C, or S, for instance?

Comment: Iterate over the reflex vertices of the polygon and check whether they're in the triangle. (You don't need to know whether the reflex vertices are ear tips.)

Comment: (For reference, [this](http://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/TriangulationByEarClipping.pdf) is the paper I'm looking at. If the algorithm it describes isn't the one you're using, we might have communication issues.)

Comment: I'm a little lost - wouldn't the vertices of the triangle always be within the polygon since the triangle is composed within the polygon?

Comment: No, the other vertices. The ones that aren't part of the triangle.

Comment: I read that document and have a general layout done for my ear clipping method. Again, if you go to page 3, where he starts paragraph 2 with "once you have a list of reflex and convex angles" is basically by bottleneck.

Comment: To figure out which side of the polygon is the inside, you can walk along it, keeping track of the total angle you turn. By the time you reach your start, you can determine which side of your path was the inside by whether you've turned 360 degrees clockwise or counterclockwise. (This can be optimized by keeping track of the quadrant your current angle is in instead of computing angles with inverse trig functions.)

Comment: That doesn't solve the answer for reflex tests - in that document, take [this](http://www.personal.kent.edu/~rmuhamma/Compgeometry/MyCG/TwoEar/two-ear.htm) one for instance - if you do the first example of ears right near the top, by the 4th ear cut you'll end up with a triangle where all points are outside the triangle but the triangle it's self is outside the polygon. I was going to do line segment testing to see if any part of the current triangle I am checking for is outside of the polygon and discarding it if it is.

Comment: You sure about that? Can you provide a picture where the reflex test fails immediately? I can't tell what the 4th ear cut in your order is.

Comment: http://i41.tinypic.com/2vl4nzd.png As you can see, 1 is a reflex (what I am trying to find) which, if tested, is outside the polygon and has 0 other vertex in it - this works with my original isinside test. 2, 3 and 4 work since they are all good and dandy and ears. 5 screws it to hell, it's central point is close to or inside the polgyon and it could come back positive, and it has 0 other vertex inside it. How do I test for that? The only way I can figure is line segment testing the created hyp of the triangle as part would be outside the triangle and striking it out for that.

Comment: Check the angle formed by the two sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out my problem was one of how I was conceiving the issue. I was saying that if the point was outside the polygon it could still be in the polygon without adding in my head the fact I removed the last vertex. Been busting my brains trying to implement ear clipping for a few days and got it wrong at this point - the solution was the basic "check if the center point of the triangle was outside the polygon and mark it as reflex".